# Exporting SQL table to Excel - column names are not exporting, only the data

Tags: sql, vba

After I connect to SQL Management Studio via Excel VBA, I have the following code (PART OF IT) that pulls the data from a table in SQL.

```vb
With BalanceSheet
    ' Assign the Connection object.
    .ActiveConnection = cnPubs
    ' Extract the required records.
    .Open "select * from Analytics.dbo.BalSheetKeyLineItemsFinal"
    Sheet1.Range("A13").CopyFromRecordset BalanceSheet
    ' Tidy up
    .Close
End With
```

HOWEVER, the column names from the table do not show up.  Is there a way I can get the column names to be included when my data is exported to Excel??

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A recordset contains the data you have queried against, so this is what you would expect to happen. Since you're using `.Open` and `.ActiveConnection`, I assume you're using ADO: In which case, you can get the field names from the recordset object's `Fields` collection:

```
For i = 0 to .Fields.Count - 1
  Sheet1.Range("A12").Offset(, i) = .Fields(i).Name
Next
```

This will write the field titles across row 12 of your `Sheet1`.

Comment: thank you, worked perfectly!  I'm not too familiar with all of the ADO properties and this definitely helped!